# Why does C not have a logical assignment operator?

Tags: c, logical-operators

I had the need to code a statement of the form

```
a = a || expr;
```

where `expr` should be evaluated and the result be assigned to `a` iff `a` is not set. this relies on the logical OR's short-circuiting capabilities.

The shorter way to write the above would, of course, be

```
a ||= expr;
```

but (to my surprise) C does not have logical assignment operators.

So my question is twofold. First, is there a shorter way to write the first statement in standard C (the ternary operator is even worse - `a = a ? a : expr` requires me to spell out `a` thrice).

Secondly, why aren't there logical assignments in C? The possible reasons I could think of are:

- it makes the grammar harder to parse?
- there is some subtlety in handling short-circuiting for these cases?
- it was considered superfluous (but isn't that an argument against ALL the operator assignments?)

**EDIT**

**Please unlock this question because:**

- The question it has been linked to (as a alleged duplicate of) HAS NOT BEEN ANSWERED. The (accepted) answer to that question states that `||=` is not present because duplicates the functionality of `|=`. That is the wrong answer. `|=` does not short-circuit.
- C and C++ are NOT the same languages. I wish to know why C doesn't have it. In fact, the fact that derived languages like C++ and, particularly, Java (which did not suffer from the problems of legacy code as has been suggested in Edmund's answer) makes the question even more interesting.

**EDIT 2**

It now seems like my original intent was wrong. In the statement `a = a || expr` (where `a` is integral and `expr` returns an integral value, first both `a` and `expr` will be implicitly converted to "booleans", and then the "boolean" value will be assigned to `a`. This will be incorrect — the integral value will be lost. Thanks, Jens and Edmund.

So for the first part of the question, the correct ways, not alternatives :), to code my intention would be:

```
if (!a) a = expr;
```

or

```
a = a ? a : expr;
```

they should be optimized the same (I think) though personally I would prefer the first one (because it has one less `a` to type).

However, the second part of the question still remains. The arguments that Jens and Edmund about have given about the ambiguity in `a ||= expr` apply equally well to `a = a || expr`. the assignment case can simply be treated as the normal one:

- convert `a` to boolean
- if it is true, the value of the entire expression becomes equal to the boolean value of `a`
- otherwise evaluate `expr`, convert result to boolean, assign to `a`, and return it

The steps above seem to be the same for both the assignment and normal case.

Comment: This question is *not* an exact duplicate of the "possible duplicate" mentioned above.  That question asks why there is no syntactic shorthand for `||=`, etc.  This question asks why C doesn't allow the trick of carrying non booleans through a boolean operator.

Comment: I was going to post an answer: It would be nice if those worked with short-circuiting.

There is the option `if ( ! a ) a = expr;` which is quite clear and concise.

As for tricks, note that addition and multiplication on Booleans produces OR and AND functions, respectively, so as long as you don't need short-circuits or a cast to `bool`, `+=` and `*=` perform like `||=` and `&&=` respectively.

Comment: Since this is prematurely closed I answer in a comment. I think this does not exist because its interpretation would be ambiguous. What value should be assigned in `a |= expr` the result of `expr` or its logical value? What should be the type of the `a |= expr` as a whole, `int`, the type of `a` or the result of promoting `a` and `expr`? I don't think that there is a straight solution to these question, and probably therefore anybody who might have considered this already has quickly abandoned. I personally would go for `a = (a ? a : expr)` and let the compiler optimize the assignment.

Comment: I think there's also an argument that can be made that a `&&=` and `||=` operator would be introducing a new semantic concept in the language, the conditional assignment. The ternary as `lvalue` is already bad enough in some compilers, don't need to add some more.

Comment: WRT || and && preserving the values: perl much? :)

Comment: There is a GCC extension `a ?: b` which means `a ? a : b` but without the extra evaluation

Comment: Adding the `&&=` and `||=` operators doesn't add any significant complexity to the compiler — it could be done as easily as `+=` was done.  Much more to the point is the minimal utility of the operators.  One issue you've raised: the result of `||` or `&&` is always 0 or 1, so the assignment operator would conditionally overwrite the LHS with either 0 or 1, depending on whether the value in the LHS was already true-like (non-zero) or false-like (zero), and on whether the RHS evaluated to true or false.  I don't recall feeling the lack of such a facility.

Comment: Indeed, the question is "even more interesting" for javascript where operands of || and && operators are NOT converted to "boolean". So proposed operators ||= and &&=  would be much more useful  in javascript than ones in strictly typed languages such as C, C++ or Java

Comment: For C++ version of this Q&A, see [Why doesn't c++ have &&= or ||= for booleans?](//stackoverflow.com/q/2488406/2157640). Note that C++ is fundamentally different from C in this regard as in C++, logical expressions are of type `bool`.

Answer (score 11):

`a ||= expr` is problematic due to short circuit evaluation of its equivalent `a = a || expr`.

To have `a ||= expr` function like `a = a || expr` consider OP's assertion:

> "In the statement `a = a || expr` ..., first both a and expr will be implicitly converted to "booleans","

This is not quite correct.  `expr` will not be converted if `a` evaluates to `true`.  This would make a difference should `expr` be something like `scanf()` or `rand()` or some function that affected the state of the program.

Code such as `a ||= scanf("%d", &i) != 1;` would only attempt to scan data with a false value in `a`.  Although it would be possible to extend the language this way, additional short-circuit operators to the current set of `||` and `&&` would likely cause more coding problems than clear simplifications.

On the other hand: A quick, if obfuscated, way to write code where functions return non-zero  codes on error.

```
// Perform functions until an error occurs.
bool error = foo1();
error &&= foo2();  // Only valid if C was extended with &&=
error &&= foo3();
```

Answer (score 5):

Because the return type of operators `||` and `&&` is not the same as type of their left argument.

The return type of `||` and `&&` is always `int`<sup>1</sup>, while the left argument may be any integral, floating point or pointer type. The operands also don't have to be of the same type. Therefore defining `x ||= y` as `x = x || y` and `x &&= y` as `x = x && y` as would be consistent with other augmented assignments would not be able to store the result in the argument for most types.

You could come up with other definitions, e.g. `x ||= y` as `if(!x) x = y` and `x &&= y` as `if(!y) x = y`, but that would not be exactly obvious and it is not *that* useful, so it was not included.

<sup>1</sup><sub>In C++ it is `bool`.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

I guess the simple answer is that `||` is a boolean operator: and in C, a "boolean" is 0 or 1.  The operands are implicitly converted to booleans (I have not checked that that's what the spec actually says, but it's how C behaves), and the result is a boolean.

Altering the semantics to support this pattern may well be feasible -- until someone relies on  `||` doing what it's always done.

Comment: There is no `boolean` type in C, so operands aren't converted to `boolean` and result of `||` and '&&` isn't `boolean`.

Comment: @qrdl You are right about `boolean` (although C99 has `_Bool`), but  `&&`, `||` (and `!`) are defined as resulting in either 0 or 1. See the C99 standard §6.5.13 and §6.5.14.

Comment: Thanks.  My use of "quotes" indicates that that's the approximate meaning of it.  If I'd bean referring to the mythical `boolean` type I would have indicated it as such.  My answer as a whole is phrased in terms of behaviour, not abstract specification.

Comment: Detail: "and the result is a boolean." --> result is type `int` with a boolean value of 0 or 1.

Answer (score 3):

I cannot find any particular reason, why the operators don't exist (in C99).

So the only reason I can find is, that there was no boolean type in C89, and those boolean operators were intended to be solely used in `if`'s.

Example:

```
int i = 5;

/* This should not make any difference,
   since or'ing with false, shouldn't change
   the value... dib di dib diddy...*/
i ||= 0; /* Actually: i = i || 0, which gives 'true' */
```

`i` is now '1'', which for most people is pretty counter intuitive.

This operator obviously doesn't bring any clearence or coding improvement without the boolean type, that would make sence being or'd with another one.

In my opinion, the implementation of `a ||= b;` as `if(!a) a = b;` would be pretty straightforward and has aleardy been implemented by e.g. Lua.

So you're question seems to be a bit, why C has been designed the way it has been designed.
If this question was about C++, you could for example ask Bjarne Stroustrup and ask him, what had went into him. Since this is not the case, this seems to me to be kind of a dead end, because the standard has been written quite some time ago and you cannot really ask people anymore, why the h***.

On the other hand, this incomplete operator set should (in my opinion) aleardy have been made whole using a similar notation than yours, since in my opinion, there is no reason against it.

I hope I could help a little.

Answer (score 0):

One simple explanation is this.

```
bool resultsComputeAll = false;
bool resultsUntilFirst = false;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    resultsComputeAll = compute(i) || resultsComputeAll;
    resultsUntilFirst = resultsUntilFirst || compute(i);
}
```

Which one would be `result ||= compute(i)`? It's ambiguous so it's better to not define.